# How to display Javascript variable in specific HTML div?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm very new to using Javascript and I want to display this variable on my homepage for my portfolio

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>

    var curDate  = new Date();
    var curYear  = curDate.getUTCFullYear(),
        curMonth = curDate.getUTCMonth(),
        curDay   = curDate.getUTCDate();

    var myYear   = 1996,
        myMonth  = 10,
        myDay    = 22;

    var myAge = curYear % myYear;
    if (curMonth < myMonth && curDay < myDay || curMonth < myMonth && curDay === myDay || curMonth == myMonth && curDay < myDay) {
      myAge  -= 1; 
    }

    var myAgeDiv = document.getElementById('my-age');
    myAgeDiv.textContent = myAge;

    $('#my-age').text(myAge);

    </script>
    <title>My eportfolio!</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="my-age"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Edit:** I've created a new html file (the same as above) with no other content external .js files and it still doesn't work. Does this mean the age displaying code is wrong?

Comment: google your query first, before asking.

Comment: I have but literally none of the solutions work I don't know if there's an error in the code

Comment: Can you show us how you tried to do it?

Comment: Check your browser console for errors, and what functions have you used to manipulate DOM?

Comment: I get this error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

Comment: I'm currently using this answer document.getElementById("your_div_id").innerHTML = myAge;

Comment: @user3797115 Can you show us your HTML?

Answer (score 3):

You may try:

```
document.getElementById("your_div_id").innerHTML = myAge;
```

Answer (score 2):

if your div have an **ID** do this using jQuery:

```
$('#DivID').text(myAge);
```

have a **class**:

```
$('.DivClass').text(myAge);
```

or using only javascrtipt:

```
document.getElementById('DivID').innerText = myAge;
```

Answer (score 2):

HTML:

```
<div id="test"></div>
```

JS:

```
var d = document.getElementById('test');
d.innerHTML = myAge;
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you've got a `<div>` like the following one:

```
<div id="my-age"></div>
```

Then you can use the `document.getElementById()` to get the div in JavaScript and edit its content:

```
var myAgeDiv = document.getElementById('my-age');

myAgeDiv.textContent = myAge;
```

Comment: And this got downvoted because...? The answer is correct, why should anyone downvote it? Please explain and do not just "random downvote" answers.

Comment: This is awful I know all these answers are great and should work but they don't. btw I up-voted

Comment: @user3797115 then you are doing something wrong! Tell us more, edit your question and add additional details.

Answer (score 2):

If your variable is your_variable
Then you can use

```
document.getElementById('DivID').innerHTML = your_variable;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using pure javascript, somehow get your element, for example:

```
var myElem = document.getElementById('my-element-id');
```

Then you can set it's `innerHTML`:

```
myElem.innerHTML = myAge.toString();
```

If you are using jQuery, things get simpler, getting your element becomes:

```
var myElem = $('#my-element-id');
```

And setting it's content:

```
myElem.html(myAge);
```

Or if you don't need to insert html and want to be safer:

```
myElem.text(myAge);
```